# Where is my DI error?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I try to make a filtered list of guidelines that are retrieved as a JSON object. However after running the code i get a DI error. Totally don't know where the error might arise? Does anybody have an idea?

The error:

> error_handler.js:54 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: DI Error
>   Error: DI Error
>       at NoProviderError.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.bundle.js:3423:33)
>       at NoProviderError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:8080/vendor.bundle.js:27156:16)
>       at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (http://localhost:8080/vendor.bundle.js:55463:16)
>       at new NoProviderError (http://localhost:8080/vendor.bundle.js:55525:16)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_.*throwOrNull (http://localhost:8080/vendor.bundle.js:74856:19)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.*getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:8080/vendor.bundle.js:74895:25)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.*getByKey (http://localhost:8080/vendor.bundle.js:74827:25)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.get (http://localhost:8080/vendor.bundle.js:74696:21)
>       at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (http://localhost:8080/vendor.bundle.js:56399:52)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.injectorGet (http://localhost:8080/vendor.bundle.js:75631:45)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.injectorGet (http://localhost:8080/vendor.bundle.js:76059:49)
>       at ElementInjector.get (http://localhost:8080/vendor.bundle.js:75135:27)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_.*getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:8080/vendor.bundle.js:74892:24)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.*getByKey (http://localhost:8080/vendor.bundle.js:74827:25)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.get (http://localhost:8080/vendor.bundle.js:74696:21

)

Here is an excerpt of the code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormArray, FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Recommendation, Question, PreReq, Topic } from '../recommendations/recommendation';

import { RecommendationService } from '../recommendations/recommendation.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-inputform',
  templateUrl: './inputform.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./inputform.component.css']
})


export class InputformComponent implements OnInit{
  inputform: FormGroup;
  Recommendations: Recommendation[];
  Guidelines: string[] = [];
  Topics: string [] = [];
  Questions: string [] = [];
  public query = '';
  public filteredList = [];
  public elementRef;
  selectedIdx: number;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, myElement: ElementRef, private RecommendationService: RecommendationService) {
    this.elementRef = myElement;
    this.selectedIdx = -1;
    this.createForm();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  this.RecommendationService
        .getRecommendations()
        .then((Recommendations: Recommendation[]) => {
        this.Recommendations = Recommendations.map((Recommendation) => {
          let checker = 0;
          console.log(Recommendation.guideline);
          for (let i = 0; i < this.Guidelines.length; i++) {
            if (Recommendation.guideline == this.Guidelines[i]) {
               checker = 1;
            }
          }
          if (checker == 0) {
            this.Guidelines.push(Recommendation.guideline);
          }
          checker = 0;

          return Recommendation;
        });
      });
```

and this is the module definition:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';  // <-- #1 import module voor reactieve forms
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RecommendationDetailsComponent } from './recommendations/recommendation-details/recommendation-details.component';
import { RecommendationListComponent } from './recommendations/recommendation-list/recommendation-list.component';
import { RecommendationSearchComponent } from './recommendations/recommendation-details/recommendation-search';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { GuidelinepageComponent } from './guidelinepage/guidelinepage.component';
import { InputformComponent } from './inputform/inputform.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RecommendationDetailsComponent,
    RecommendationListComponent,
    RecommendationSearchComponent,
    GuidelinepageComponent,
    InputformComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule 
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: As well as the error, you should provide your module definition as this is probably where the issue is.

Comment: (and this is Angular, not angularjs - you should change your label).

Comment: Is RecommendationService using the `@Injectable()` decorator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're not providing your `RecommendationService`

try modifying the providers section in your module code to:

```
providers: [ RecommendationService ],
```